# Keras fit_generator only useful for data augmentation, or also for reading from disk(/network)

Tags: keras, bigdata

Data might not fit in GPU-memory (including activations and gradients), for which one uses mini-batches, and it might not fit in RAM, for which one uses `fit_generator`. Or at least, the latter is my hypothesis I would like to validate here.

Is it true that Keras applies a producer-consumer strategy to first load the yielded elements of the generator into RAM until (or while not) `queue_size` is filled, and then keeps on filling it whenever batches are popped to train the network? The documentation mentions that this is useful to use the CPU for data augmentation and the GPU for training. Is the use case where this producer-consumer parallelism is used to load the data from disk, into RAM because it doesn't fit in RAM at once, also valid? My data has 100k CT-scans, which obviously do not fit in RAM.

Summarized, is `fit_generator` only to be used to parallelize data pre-processing and training, or can it also be (sensibly) used to parallelize data loading (to RAM) and training? Or would the latter be like using a hammer to get a screw in the wall?

Comment: Juts try to figure out your situation. Can you fit a single CT image in RAM? If so, there is no problem with fit_generator since you can always set batch size as small as possible.

Comment: You can definitely fit one or more CT's in memory, yet at most 5-25% of all of them on a reasonable high performance computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use it to parallelize data loading, that is one of the common use cases, for example when training with ImageNet-sized datasets.

But note that if you parallelize too much (too many workers) then usually IO becomes the bottleneck.

Comment: Check! I would guess there is not much to do though, since in general one should train the whole data set per epoch, and can't really prevent over-fitting on the first pieces if you first train N>1 epochs on the first piece that fits in memory, then N epochs on the second, fine-tuning N such that IO is not a bottle-neck anymore. So the better solution to IO bottlenecking would be a more complicated model or *maybe* N > 1 but also divide the learning_rate by N, such that gradient decent is similar to 1 epoch, but goes 'smoother'?

Comment: Or of course, install faster storage infrastructure :)